# How to get VScode terminal to use packages installed on Mac terminal via composer

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, zsh

I installed composer using home brew on my Utilities terminal on my Mac.
When I try to use packages installed through composer, I get that it isn't installed.  For example, I can run `laravel new appname` in the Mac terminal, but it won't let me run it in VScode terminal (using zsh).  I get the error `zsh: command not found: laravel`.

Can someone help so that the VScode terminal uses the packages installed in my Mac terminal?

My /etc/paths file looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/Users/melaniecarr/.composer/vendor/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the relevant directories to your PATH in `~/.zshenv`. Try `which laravel` in the shell that works to see what directories you need to add. E.g.:

```
❯ which watch
/usr/local/bin/watch

❯ export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" # needs to be in ~/.zshenv to be permanent
```